# An unrecoverable stack overflow has occurred

Tags: java, c, java-native-interface, stack-overflow

I am trying to integrate Java and C functions and I am having some trouble.
I am trying to initialize a variable in this way char DataString[32][900]; and I keep on getting "An unrecoverable stack overflow has occurred."
If I remove it then the program doesn't crash any more.
Do you have any ideas what is causing it?

Comment: Could you provide some more context and code?

Comment: You need to put waaay more detail on the question.

Comment: 30k seems a little small to trigger a stack overflow

Comment: @DavidHeffernan - All you really need is 1: http://stackoverflow.com/privileges/create-posts

Answer (score 8):

By the sounds of it, you are (in effect) allocating a large array on a Java thread's stack (while calling a C method), and this is causing the stack to overrun.  This would be "irrecoverable" because writing beyond the end of the stack could have trampled whatever appears next in memory<sup>1</sup>.  In the face of potential memory corruption, the JVM has no choice but to bail out.

If this diagnosis is correct, then the solution is to not allocate big data structures on the stack in your C code!  Allocate them using `malloc` instead ... and don't forget to `free` them or you'll have a native code memory leak to track down.

Alternatively, you could try using larger Java thread stacks:

- The `-Xss<size>` option changes the default stack size.  This potentially affects all threads.
- Some overloads of the `Thread` constructor have a parameter for overriding the default stack size.

---

<sup>1 - By contrast, if a pure Java method causes a stack overflow, this is *always* detected before the code has a chance to trample other stacks or data structures.  Hence, it is safe for the JVM to throw `StackOverflowError` and give the application the opportunity to try to recover.</sup>

Comment: I wish I could mark this answer as the solution. I was having a similar problem when trying to pass a large array from Apache Spark to C++ and viceversa. The solution was exactly as @Stephen C says, by increasing the thread stack size. In the case of Spark, the thread stack size associated with each worker node can be changed by modifying the file $SPARK_HOME/conf/spark-defaults.conf (with spark.executor.extraJavaOptions -Xss10M, if you want the stack size be 10MB).
Thank you very much.